# I am adding images to my UITabBarItem and get gray boxes instead of items to appear. How can I fix this?

Tags: ios, image, xcode5

I have the following images in my Images.xcassets folder:

[image: Location of the images]

And I have my storyboard set up as follows:

[image: Storyboard setup]

Why am I getting these grey boxes instead of actual images?  Note: the boxes show up in the simulator and the storyboard.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because your images are only available in 1x scale but your simulator runs a retina device. Try a @2x.png version in your images.xcasstes.